# GWT Sourcemaps with IE 11

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-11, source-maps, ie11-developer-tools

How can I use GWT SuperDevMode source maps with IE11? Does it work at all?
I tried to right click the file tab in IE debugger view and the "choose source map" option. However, the file dialog only accepts *.map file and looks like it doesn't understand sourcemap json files.

[image]

Everything works great in Chrome, unfortunately the issue I'm looking into is IE only :-(

Answer (score 2):

It should work just fine. Maybe it`s not so obvious how to start debugging.

First select a JAVA source file:

[image]

The list can be full of other files so the easiest way is to start typing the file name.

When you have your source file opened you can set break points.